# Codeigniter, form_dropdown disable or result in label [PHP]

Tags: php, codeigniter

Guys can you help me put the below echo result into label, and not in the dropdown menu? Alternatively can you tell me how to disable the below dropdown menu?

My code looks as follows:

```
    <?php $owner_id = array();

    $owner_id['0'] = '-';
    foreach ($project->project_has_workers as $workers):
    $owner_id[$workers->user_id] = $workers->user->firstname.' '.$workers->user->lastname;
    endforeach;
    if(isset($project)){$user = $project->owner_id;}else{$user = $this->user->id;}

    echo form_dropdown('owner_id', $owner_id, $user,  
   'style="width:100%" class="label label-default"');

    ?>
```

Any help really appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say label?

Comment: label means whatever. I just wanna to put above echo in something which not allow user to click/open the drop down menu.

Comment: I think you would need to use javascript in that case.

Comment: if you want to hard-code disable the element, then why even have it in the first place? otherwise use js if its dependent on something

Answer (score 0):

```
echo form_dropdown('owner_id', 
$owner_id, $user,  'style="width:100%" 
disabled="disabled" class="label label-default"');
```

One of the solution :)
Is there any possible to show echo outside the dropdown menu?